# Can not obtain proof of ticket cancellation from Wizz Air

Tags: cancellations, wizz-air

I have cancelled my tickets for a Wizz Air flight. The refund is not the issue as "cancellation fees were higher than ticket price" and all that, but I need to have a cancellation confirmation in order to get some of that money via a travel insurance that I had made.

The thing is, I have received no such confirmation and a call center rep said that it "might arrive" in a week—that has also passed, and none arrived.

What else could I do to obtain said cancellation confirmation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call them again and again every few days. Not much else you can do. To lower your costs, check the [contact us](https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/contact/contact-us) page click `See all centers` and then search for +361 -- those are non-premium numbers and they can be called from any country.